# virtual machine setup does not start

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, windows-10

Excuse me for my beginner question. I tried to find solution for my problem by searching in `Google` but I could not find any thing.

Recently I migrated from windows and so I am new to `Ubuntu 14.04`. But I need to continue some works in `Windows` yet. So I installed `Oracle VM VirtualBox` and tried to create a virtual machine of type `Windows 10` as described [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/try-windows-10-youre-running-linux/) except of I used a boot able DVD. Before I could install `Windows 10` by that DVD but now when I try to create virtual machine, screen remains in this state and setup does not start:

[image]

Do you know what cause this problem? How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In a virtual machine, Windows 10 needs the host (your computer) processor to support Intel VT-x/AMD-v. AMD-v is always enabled, but Intel VT-x is usually disabled, so you probably have an Intel processor. Try going into your BIOS (the startup screen should say something like `Press [some key] to enter Setup`, press that key) and look for an option like “Intel Virtualization Technology,” “Intel VT-x,” “Virtualization Extensions,” “Vanderpool,” or something like that and enable it. Hopefully that should solve the problem. More information: [How to Enable Intel VT-x in Your Computer’s BIOS or UEFI Firmware at the How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/)